# Complex Gaussian Integral $\int N(z; \mu, \sigma) \log(N(z; 0, I))dz$

Tags: analysis, gaussian-integral

I am new to the field of Gaussian integration, could anyone help me to solve this integration and give me a detailed explanation of each step?
The equation is as follow where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ refers to the mean and s.d and z has a dimensional of J:

$ \int N(z; \mu, \sigma)\log(N(z; 0, I))dz$

Many thanks in advance!!!

Edited to to include a bit more details, I could personally solve $ \int N(z; 0, I)dz$, but don't know how to deal with this complex integral, and I am not sure about the multi-dimensional case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have edit the question a bit.